# Why does this cube not rotate around its own axes?

Tags: matrix, rotation, three.js

I've got a cube which I would like to rotate around its own axes in 3D space by using keyboard input.  The cube is still rotating around the world axes.

Here's my code:

```
var rotation_matrix_y, rotation_matrix_x, rotation_matrix_z;

var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00, wireframe: true});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
var axisHelper = new THREE.AxisHelper( 5 );

cube.add( axisHelper );
scene.add(cube);
cube.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
cube.matrix.makeRotationFromEuler(cube.rotation);

var render = function () {
document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);

    function onKeyDown(e) {                 
        // W - up
    if (e.keyCode == 87) {
        rotation_matrix_x = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(.0001);
    cube.applyMatrix(rotation_matrix_x);
        }               
    // S - down
    if (e.keyCode == 83) {
    rotation_matrix_x = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(-0.0001);
    cube.applyMatrix(rotation_matrix_x);
    }
        // D - right
    if (e.keyCode == 68) {
    rotation_matrix_y = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(-0.0001);
    cube.applyMatrix(rotation_matrix_y);
        }
        // A - left
    if (e.keyCode == 65) {
    rotation_matrix_y = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(0.0001);
    cube.applyMatrix(rotation_matrix_y);
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(render);

        stats.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera); 
};
```

There are a couple of questions similar to this one, but they all seem to be outdated and some of the methods have been deprecated.

Comment: Try `cube.rotateX( 0.01 );` or `cube.rotateY( -0.01 );`

Comment: Those methods were available on the matrices, but have been deprecated as well and removed.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? Are you using three.js r.66?

Comment: Apologies, nothing happened when I applied them to the cube itself.  I got the deprecation warning when I called it on the matrix.  I am using r.66.  Should I be calling some other method to apply the rotateX/Y?

Comment: I added the following line while testing and it caused your suggestion to break:cube.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(cube.matrix);
Please add your initial suggestion as the answer and I will mark it as solved.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to rotate an object on its own x-axis is like so:

```
object.rotateX( radians );
```

There is also `object.rotateY( radians );` and `object.rotateZ( radians );`

three.js r.66